# How to find sibling element of a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html that looks like this:

```
<h3>
<a href="google.com">hellw</a>
</h3>
<ol>
  <li>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>
<h3>
<a href= "dddd">dddd</a>
</h3>
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>
```

I want to get ol next to h3. I have tried this but it isnt working

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
print(soup.h3.next_element)
```

This gives out a inside of h3. How do I get all the ols in a list?

Edit:

I have tried this but it only gives me lis within the first ol `tags = soup.h3.nextSibling.find_all()`

and not all ols.

I need ols in a list so I could iterate it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first grab all `h3` tags in a list. Once you have this done, just find all `ol` tags while iterating through that list. It would look something like this:

```
html_string = """
   ...
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')

# all h3 tags
h3_tags = soup.find_all('h3')

# all ol tags
ol_tags = [each_h3.find_next('ol') for each_h3 in h3_tags]
```

This will give you output of:

```
[<ol>
<li>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>, <ol>
<li>
<ol>
  ....
  </ol></li>
</ol>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a faster match using a CSS [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to specify the `ol` immediately following the `h3`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<h3>
<a href="google.com">hellw</a>
</h3>
<ol>
  <li>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>
<h3>
<a href= "dddd">dddd</a>
</h3>
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select('h3 + ol'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the next ol list, you can do it this way:

```py
html_string = """<h3>
<a href="google.com">hellw</a>
</h3>
<ol>
  <li>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>
<h3>
<a href= "dddd">dddd</a>
</h3>
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
print(soup.find('h3').find_next('ol'))
```

Output:

```
<ol>
<li>
  ....
  </li>
</ol>
```